# Inkscape- How to keep the outline of the sprocket

Tags: inkscape

I want to use the outline of the sprocket and inside it i want to put an alaphabet.. how to remove the inner part and make it all one color.?[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD, web0405! Please cam you improve your question telling us something about your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw a black circle which covers the white parts, you want to remove.
2. Mark the sprocket and your circle (as paths).
3. Choose 'path unite'.